# 405 Method Not Allowed With Postman And a Public GraphQl API

Tags: graphql, postman

I´m new in GraphQl and I´m trying to get a response using Postman Web and a public GraphQl API ->
For the API, I´m using exactly this address :

`https://graphql.org/swapi-graphql?query=query%20%7B%0A%20%20allFilms%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20films%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20title%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D`

So, in postman, I just did this :

[image]

In the Authorization tab I have this:

[image]

What I´m doing wrong here?, is there is some Header missing?

Comment: query encoded in url = GET method while almost all graphQL server works with POST method, follow some [better] tutorial

Answer (score 1):

So, at the end I was doing several this wrong. First of all, the address was wrong ->

https://swapi-graphql.netlify.app/.netlify/functions/index ( this is the one )

and second, the right way to do this in PostMan is ->

[image]

Comment: Check out GraphQL radio button. I hope you get more from there. 